# Performance bottleneck with JSONP request (long evaluating time)

Tags: performance, profiling, jsonp

I have to use JSONP request to get large JSON (around 80kB, array of 100 object with multiple big properties). When browser is evaluating request I cant do anything with the page, browser is freezed. I suppose, JSON is evaluating and it uses UI thread.
What can I do to speed this up? Sometimes "Evaluate script" event (I use Timeline in DevTools) takes 3.5s (sic!).
I cant use regular AJAX request because of CORS, I cant enable CORS on server. I dont want to make 10 smaller requests because then I will have to rerender layout 10 times or more...

Comment: why do you have to rerender 10 times, when using 10 small requests? just gather all data and then rerender once.

Comment: Well, yes, I can cache data, but anyway - smaller requests also freeze browser, but for 0.3 - 0.5s. It is some solution, but I am looking for something more efficient.

Comment: Ok, I have portionet my request, now performance is much better.